# Windows incorrect internet time after Iran rejects to use DST

Tags: windows, ntp

Recently Iranian Parliament rejected to move forward an hour for DST and the current and correct time is at: https://time.ir

My Windows uses internet time but it is an hour ahead (for example now the real time is 11:12 A.M., but Windows says it's 12:12 P.M.).

I tried updating and had no updates, I tried manually changing the NTP server and syncing that which synced but the time did not change.

Are there anyways to automatically change the time to correct one rather than changing manually the time one hour before?

Comment: It's even worse in USA, where cities and Native American reservations may choose different DST standards from state, e.g. Arizona (https://travelness.com/arizona-time-zone). Just pick another time zone.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik but Iran has only one time zone. For example last year the time was one hour ahead starting the spring, but this year the parliament ruled not to change that:( I'm not sure if picking another time zone is a good choice because I have to revert it to Tehran six months later:(

Comment: Can't you choose another timezone than Iran?

Comment: @harrymc I think applications which tracking me based on my IP and time will get confused (not sure which ones), but I prefer not to change that. But no I cannot change that, because none of other time zones (even the ones an hour ahead or past comparing to Tehran) are not correct in this situations. It's hard to explain by writing but the short answer is a No.

Comment: Workaround: Use UTC time (prime-meridian time), which is a universal standard, particularly in computer science and astronomy. ;-) BTW, most Linux distros use that as default.

Comment: Seems like you'll need to disable the automatic time sync, and replace by a script that will run after login to get the official time for Tehran and add the offset.

Answer (score 0):

The simple workaround is to turn off Automatic Time Zone, so that Windows lets you turn off the so-called Daylight Saving option. With the Daylight Saving off, you can then turn the Automatic Time Zone back on to fully enjoy the automatic date and time on Windows.

In the meantime, as an explanation of the problem for our non-Iranian friends, Iran is among the few countries where the time difference to GMT is some full hours PLUS A HALF HOUR (i.e., +3:30). This fact makes it impossible for us to simply change the time zone to another time zone differing at exactly 1 hour to IRST since such a time zone does not exist at all.